# Watch 2 Language Specific Issue

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm working on a watch App. The Xcode version is 7.3, Swift 2 , iPhone 5 and watch version 3.1.3

First thing Mobile app and watch App both works properly on simulator.The App has two version (English/ Chinese). Now the problem is When I select the english Language for watch, App Works as I needed. But if I change the watch Language to Chinese or any other language then the App Shows a Spinner for long time and then return a black screen. Is anyone facing Same Issue??Please suggest me what is wrong with this app??  Thanks in advance.

```html
Incident Identifier: 9611567E-C66A-4016-A07D-464B0D0F46CB
CrashReporter Key:   f90545bedbe3c3364591ded5495f1209af31a874
Hardware Model:      Watch2,4
Process:             iCE Angel ID WatchApp [276]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5DC3CFAC-91A8-475D-8B36-60D5353F38E3/iCE Angel ID WatchApp.app/iCE Angel ID WatchApp
Identifier:          com.iceangelid.app.watchkit
Version:             1.1.1 (1.1.1)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.iceangelid.app.watchkit [343]


Date/Time:           2017-10-25 15:26:48.9193 +0530
Launch Time:         2017-10-25 15:25:56.0000 +0530
OS Version:          Watch OS 3.1.3 (14S960)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1f1896e0 0x1f185000 + 18144
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1f1894ac 0x1f185000 + 17580
2   CoreFoundation                 0x1f516818 0x1f45d000 + 759832
3   CoreFoundation                 0x1f514adc 0x1f45d000 + 752348
4   CoreFoundation                 0x1f469414 0x1f45d000 + 50196
5   GraphicsServices               0x20c04e1e 0x20bf9000 + 48670
6   UIKit                          0x23ea20be 0x23e2d000 + 479422
7   UIKit                          0x23e9cf08 0x23e2d000 + 458504
8   SockPuppetGizmo                0x2a4d0ace 0x2a4c9000 + 31438
9   libdyld.dylib                  0x1f0ac566 0x1f0a9000 + 13670



Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1f25d1a0 0x1f259000 + 16800

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x10004005    r1: 0x07000806      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000c00
    r4: 0x00001b03    r5: 0xffffffff      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x002b6e08
    r8: 0x14e5dd88    r9: 0x014dccdc     r10: 0x07000806     r11: 0x07000806
    ip: 0xffffffe1    sp: 0x002b6dc0      lr: 0x1f1894ad      pc: 0x1f1896e0
  cpsr: 0x60000010

Binary Images:
0x100000 - 0x103fff iCE Angel ID WatchApp armv7k  <7c65269026583b9eb4c246f5eb0d09ce> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/5DC3CFAC-91A8-475D-8B36-60D5353F38E3/iCE Angel ID WatchApp.app/iCE Angel ID WatchApp
0x140000 - 0x16ffff dyld armv7k  <40c16d46fa443776b664db9a54fcd325> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1eb9c000 - 0x1eb9ffff libSystem.B.dylib armv7k  <acc06d05ed6537c2a5f58cf93c84188b> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x1eba0000 - 0x1ebe3fff libc++.1.dylib armv7k  <97e755cc71ae3b86b896f3ac8408fe1a> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1ebe4000 - 0x1ebfffff libc++abi.dylib armv7k  <10a460aa3dbc3a2e929eea18e8e9f2a3> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr7m9.png][1]

One more thing that i forgot to mention is the app works properly on real devices when installed first time but if I uninstall the app and then reinstall it this produce the same issue as mentioned above.

Comment: is your storyboard also correctly configured for localisation ?

Comment: @Shubhank Actually I have implemented localisation first time in this app and I have done all the changes as suggested in the tutorial.

Comment: @Shubhank One thing that i have noticed is the resource language Option do not  show the base option for all files.In the tutorial resource language option show Base for all.Please check the attached image. Is it a big Issue ??

Comment: did you check multiple times running, it might be just that the watch process is timing out ?

Comment: @Shubhank I have added the system log for watch. Please check this Maybe useful for resolving issue.